# How can I start a server in a background thread and know that the server did not throw exception on startup?

Tags: java, multithreading, oop, concurrency

I have a class which encapsulates a Server Socket i.e. a server functionality.
The interface of the class is:

```
class Server{  
  public void start();  
  public void stop();  
}
```

the start is as follows:

```
public void start(){  
   ExecutorService tp = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();  
   while(!stop){  
    try {  
        Socket clientConnection = serverSocket.accept();  
        tp.execute(new ClientProcessor(clientConnection));                
    } catch (IOException e) {  
            stop = true;
    }  
   }
```

I have trouble figuring out how I would start this without blocing my `main`.
I mean I need to start the server from a background thread so I thought of the following:

```
ExecutorService tp2 = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();  
 tp.submit(new Runnable(){  
     public void run(){  
    Server s = new Server();
        s.start();  
     }  
 });  
}
```

But what I want is to know that the server started and did not throw an exception. How can I do that?
I.e. how can I know from my `main` thread that the background server started fine and so I can continue with the rest actions?

Comment: There are a couple of problems with your code, firstly what is the `ExecutorService tp` for? you don't seem to use it? Also shouldn't your server actually implement Thread or Runnable if you want to run it in the background?

Comment: @RudolphEst:`tp` is being used on `start`.Server accepts connections and submits them to `tp`

Comment: What I meant was that your start method never uses the `tp` variable but rather submissions are made to `singleThreadManager`.

Comment: Maybe if you explained exactly what you want your server to do, we'll be able to give you a better answer (more detail on which threads you really need). Looking at your while loop it seems that your server is going to fail as soon as the first Exception occurs when calling `ServerSocket.accecpt()`, which is a rather strange way for a server to behave. Wouldn't you want the server to keep running even though a single accept failed?

Comment: @RudolphEst:I guess that depends on whether all `IOException` are recoverable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the server.
Wait a bit.
Try to connect to it on the local stack.  If the connect succeeds, you have a winner - just close the temp connection.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of doing this would be to collect all exceptions in a collection and return them to the foreground thread at some point in time.

```
class Server{  
    private Collection<? extends Exception> exceptions = new ArrayList<Exception>();

    public void start()
    {
      try{ /* do something*/ }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
          exceptions.add(e)
      }
    }

    public void stop();

    public Collection<Exception> getAllExceptions()
    {
        return exceptions;
    }

    public boolean checkOk()
    {
        return 0 == exceptions.size();
    }    

}
```

---

Elaboration on how to transfer data between threads:

If you declared your server similarly to my suggestion above, then we can change the code you have used to spawn your server to transfer the `serverStartupOk` information:

```
ExecutorService tp2 = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();  
final boolean[] result = new boolean[1]; //Final object so it can pass between threads
 tp.submit(new Runnable(){  
     public void run(){  
    Server s = new Server();
        s.start();  
        result[0] = s.checkOk(); // Retrieve the check from the server, store it in 
                                 // final array variable
     }  
 });

boolean serverStartupOk = result[0];
System.out.println("Server startup succesful: " + Boolean(serverStartupOk).toString());
}
```

Comment: I am not interested in learning specific exception.I only need to know that there was not exception or any exception

Comment: @Jim the `checkOk()` method that Ph4g3 put in his sample code gives you what you want. Just remove the `getAllExceptions()` method if you don't want it.

Comment: @Jim Yep, the `checkOk()` method will do this. If exceptions exists, `checkOk()` will return false and you can do some exception handling then (probably by using `getAllExceptions()` to determine the correct course of action).

Comment: @Jim Answer updated to explain how to use new server code between threads.

Comment: If all goes well `s.start();` does not return.That is the core problem

Comment: @Jim - make start() return if all goes well!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a *very* simple example (though there are many better - and more complicated - ways):

```
interface Server implements Thread{
    public void startup();
    public void shutdown();
}

class MyServer implements Server{
    private Exception serverError=null;
    ExecutorService singleThreadManager;

    public Exception getServerError(){
        return serverError;
    }

    public void run(){    
       while(!stop){  
            try {  
                 Socket clientConnection = serverSocket.accept();  
                 singleThreadManager.execute(new ClientProcessor(clientConnection));               
            } catch (IOException e) { 
                 serverError = e;
                 // stop = true;
                 shutdown(); // shutdown cleanly after exception
            }
       } 
    } 

    public void startup(){
       singleThreadManager = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        // do setup tasks and then
        start(); // thread.run() will now be called asynchronously
    }
}

public static void main (String ... args){
    MyServer s = new MyServer();
    s.startup();
    // whenever you want you can now call
    Exception x = s.getServerError();
    // to see whether the server has shutdown because of an error.
}
```

Comment: This will never work.`s.getServerError();` could return `null` because of thread scheduling

Comment: It would return null if you invoke it immediately. But at some point in the future you will get the right result (for instance, sleep for 5 seconds and then check again). If this solution is too simplistic, you will need to change your code to use the submit method on the `ExecutorSerice` and use the Future to check whether your task completed or not and what the exceptions were, if any, but the you cannot catch the exception in your code, or it will not be propagated up to your newly created Future.

Comment: I agree that my simple method is not the way to do it in a enterprise environment, but from your code and question, I was assuming something a little smaller/simpler.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can implement an Event Handler into your main application. Your main application should be registered as eventlistener to your server class.

Please have a look at the following link, it shows you an example of event handling for C# and the same example for Java

http://scatteredcode.wordpress.com/2011/11/24/from-c-to-java-events/

Comment: Event handlers are a good way to go, but then you get even more threads that you have to worry about, because events should not be fired on the main thread, nor on the server thread, but should instead be queued in a separate event queue and related thread. This was a simple question that can be answered with a simple change.

Answer (score 0):

Use your own `ThreadPoolExecutor` instead of the pre-baked ones in `Executors`. Then override the `afterExecute` hook provided by TPE to do whatever you want with the exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading a bit between the lines here, but it looks like you want to know if the initial listen on the socket succeeded or not. If you wanted to wait and see if any client failed, then there would be no need to run it in a different thread.

If that's correct, then you can catch any exceptions emitted by the initial TCP server socket instantiation before you start the thread to handle client connections. Pass the server in to the new thread, instead of creating it in the new thread.