# How can I know if a task submitted to executor threw exception?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, executor

If I run a thread in a `ExecutorService` is there a way to know that this thread did not throw an exception when it started execution?

Comment: By "If I run a thread", do you mean calling [ExecutorService#execute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute(java.lang.Runnable))

Comment: It looks like you are asking [the question again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159453/how-can-i-start-a-server-in-a-background-thread-and-know-that-the-server-did-not/15159778#comment21348064_15159778) because you don't like the answers you got before.

Comment: @RudolphEst:I believe that the details in the OP obscured it.I could not delete it so I re-wrote the core problem here

Comment: @Jim that is understandable. But without the details of the original question, some of your comments here are out of context. I think your first OP was just right.

Answer (score 6):

As per [the JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.lang.Runnable%29), you can submit your runnable the the executor using `submit()`

```
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Future f = service.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            throw new RuntimeException("I failed for no reason");
        }
    });
    try {
        f.get();            
    } catch (ExecutionException ee) {
        System.out.println("Execution failed " + ee.getMessage());
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        System.out.println("Execution failed " + ie.getMessage());
    }
```

This method will only work when your exceptions are unchecked. If you have checked exceptions, rethrow them wrapped in a `RuntimeException` or use the `Callable` instead of `Runnable` interface.

Comment: `f.get();` is blocking.If there is no exception it will *never* return

Comment: Thats not true, in my example it will always return. If your runnable is never going to end, then you have to periodically check again and again (see  Mikhail Vladimirov's answer), just like you would in your other question. Just check for exceptions periodically using a timer if you want. If you do not like these solutions you will have to create a better framework (like a future for every client or eventing).

Answer (score 2):

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool (4);

Future <?> future = executor.submit (new Runnable ()
{
    @Override
    public void run () {
        // while (true);
        throw new RuntimeException ("Something bad happend!");
    }
});

Thread.sleep (1000L);

try
{
    future.get (0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
catch (TimeoutException ex)
{
    System.out.println ("No exceptions");
}
catch (ExecutionException ex)
{
    System.out.println ("Exception happend: " + ex.getCause ());
}
```

Comment: Yes this would work.But it involves hard-coded delays.That is error-prone IMHO

Comment: To be fair, your answer is more complete than mine, including `get()` timeouts and generics.

Comment: @Jim Could you clarify when exactly thread is considered as "started"?

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov:If serverSocket opens and the `accept` has not thrown any bind exception.So the backend server thread "listens" for connections

Comment: @Jim In case of such a complicated "started" definition, you better set some flag in thread after it started and check this flag from other threads.

Answer (score 0):

Just said this in your other question: Use your own `ThreadPoolExecutor` instead of the pre-baked ones in `Executors`. Then override the `afterExecute` hook provided by TPE to do whatever you want with the exceptions.

Comment: From javadoc:`Method invoked upon completion of execution of the given Runnable` Upon completion means **after** my server terminates

Comment: @Jim The exception would cause your `Runnable` to terminate. If it doesn't then the question is worded wrong.

Comment: @RalfH I agree that this would work, but it seems like overkill. I've used pre-baked pooled executors in many parts of many projects and found their existing frameworks `Future.get()` methods and the exceptions it can throw to be more than adequate.

Comment: if you want to prevent termination, you could catch it in the Runnable that goes to the Executor.

Comment: @RudolphEst: in most cases, yes. Just thought overriding afterExecute gives a bit more control. Not sure what the OP wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

`get()` method of `Future` throws an `ExecutionException` if there was an exception in the thread that was executing the task. The actual exception that occurred in wrapped in this exception.